# Input box not consistent

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why is my input box is not consistent? When I add it, it increases in width.
I know is due to the col control but is making a bit messy here the image below

[image]

Here my code i am using

I am using Css with

```
.flex{
      display: flex;
 }
```

To make it that the symbol will stay with the input but however it is combined together is there a way where i can make that such input box is consistent?

```js
const $container = $('#contactContainer')
$(".remove").eq(0).hide()
$container.on('click', ".ar", function(e) {
  const add = $(this).is(".add");
  const $phones = $container.find(".phone");
  const len = $phones.length;
  if (add) {
    const $newPhone = $phones.eq(0).clone(true)
    $newPhone.find("[name=contact]")
      .attr("id", `new_${$phones.length}`)
      .val("");
    $container.append($newPhone);
    $newPhone.find(".add").remove()
    $newPhone.find(".remove").show()
  } else {
    $(this).closest(".phone").remove()
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="contact" class="col-2 col-form-label">Contact:</label>
  <style>
  .flex{ display: flex; }
  </style>
  <div class="col-4" id="contactContainer">
    <div class="flex phone" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
      <input style="margin-right: 10px;" id="validationcontact" name="contact" type="text" class="form-control" pattern="\b\d{8}\b" required>
      <input type="button" class="ar add" value="Add more field!" style="cursor: pointer;">
      
      <span class="ar remove"><label style="cursor: pointer; padding-top: 5px;"><i data-feather="minus">-</i></label></span>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Format your code proparly.

Comment: I guess you're using Bootstrap CSS with JQuery.js right? But we need such information to help you. Moreover, the thing with HTML/CSS/JS is, the error could be anywhere... Please specify a minimal reproducible example. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I made you a snippet as usual and you need to add relevant CSS to the snippet I made you

Comment: sure is it the previous one ? i did i have follow exact prolly i worry cos there many code there in the form and is using kendo ui as well with jquery javascript ajax html bootstrap 5

Comment: What do you mean. I did not copy the code from the other answer. I took the code you posted here and made a snippet  - this is YOUR job, but I do it because I am curious. I added bootstrap 5 but I cannot add the feather icons

Comment: it could be my css also i need to check thanks okay i know what the issue reedditing here

Comment: it have been updated in the code snippet as well so this is what i am experiencing

Comment: You have the text input _and_ the button in a div that has `display: flex`, and for the new fields, you only have the text input (plus the span with the `-`), also wrapped in such a flex div - so _of course_ it stretches wider.

Comment: is there for me to fix this ? 
as this is in a form where i use div to control the style 
because i wan my button and minus to be with the same as input i have to put that else it look a bit weird

Comment: You would need to explicitly specify the width of the input fields, or use something other than flex. And in general, maybe you should go read up on some basics of layouting using current CSS techniques somewhere ...? You asked a lot of "how to" questions here recently regarding that topic, most of which I would consider to be touching on rather basic stuff.

Comment: sry u are being rude because i try the basic stuff dont work that why i come here and i try and it dont work where i go next ?  And Css there so many different style how i know which ? i already try the position and is not what i wan the reason why  i use flex is i dont wan my position to be fixed as is it a dynamic site

Answer (score 0):

Solve it by a simple solution by indicating style on width

```
Style="width: 200px;"
```